# Lets Encrypt 403 Error When Installing certbot-auto on legacy (EOL) SNI is required error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, lets-encrypt, certbot

Good day,

I am trying to create a test server with an EOL set up - `Ubuntu 14.04`, `php5.5`.

I am trying to install `certbot-auto 1.9.0`. I understand this is EOL and really shouldn't be used. However, we do have servers which are still using it successfully with little issues.

When I am trying to install `certbot-auto 1.9.0` I am receiving the following error. Is there anyway to get around this issue?

````
Installing Python packages...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.KuBN6fzZPB/pipstrap.py", line 182, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/tmp.KuBN6fzZPB/pipstrap.py", line 163, in main
    for path, digest in PACKAGES]
  File "/tmp/tmp.KuBN6fzZPB/pipstrap.py", line 122, in hashed_download
    response = opener(using_https=parsed_url.scheme == 'https').open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SNI is required```
````

Comment: Had this problem on an old Debian so I manually downloaded and compiled a newer python (2.7.13) and copied over the version that certbot uses. Don't know if it would work on Ubuntu though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/old-ubuntu-14-04-how-to-continue-to-use-lets-encrypt/158995/2) on the LetsEncrypt discussion board, it's not possible to use Certbot/`certbot-auto` at all with Ubuntu 14.04 anymore (likely because Certbot tries to update itself, and is no longer able to on Ubuntu 14.04).

[acme.sh](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) is a different LetsEncrypt client that possibly works.

Comment: The reason seems to be that PyPI (used when doing `pip install`) now uses SNI, which isn't supported in Python 2.7.6 – the version included in Ubuntu 14.04.
Interestingly, this also means that `pip install` doesn't work at all in Python 2.7.6 :P

Comment: References on SNI support: [No SNI support in Python 2.7.6](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=836834), PyPI no longer supports non-SNI clients as of May 2021 ([1](https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb), [2](https://community.plone.org/t/pypi-deprecation-of-support-for-non-sni-clients-breaks-buildout-for-older-plone-versions/13803))